# What's this gesture called?

Tags: expressions, gestures

It's used to be pretty frequent in movies where I think the person after accomplishing a big task would want to convey to the viewers that "I am awesome and a hot-shot". It starts with bringing your fingers (curled towards the palm) close to your mouth and blowing air on the nails and then wiping something off the left side of chest with your fingers(or nails?). Does there exist a concise phrase I could write instead of describing the whole act? If this on topic, what was the origin of this gesture?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because gestures are not English Language.

Comment: @BrianHooper I would suggest that gestures are very much part of the English language. If you go to France you will see that theirs are often quite different. That probably applies to other language groups too.

Comment: @BrianHooper - The O.P. is asking about the _name_ of the gesture, and _polishing your fingernails_ is English. (That said, I could see why someone might vote to migrate this to ELL. A question asking for the name of a commonly-known item or gesture would be perfectly on-topic there.)

Comment: @J.R., you are quite right. I stand corrected.

Comment: @J.R. The gesture may be common, but the term for it may not be.

Comment: such a good question - esoteric too!!

Comment: It's pretty silly to claim that hand or face gestures are part of any particular spoken language. Sure, they may be correlated culturally. But the gesture is not part of the spoken language (the gestures are one-offs that stand alone). That said, this question is on topic in order to ask how to refer to such a gesture _in English_.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The gesture is polishing one's fingernails.  You mimic blowing some moisture from your breath onto your polished fingernails and using that to restore the shine by rubbing them on your jacket or shirt front.  It means, "That impressive thing I just did?  I'm so good that it caused me no more trouble than dulling my manicure a bit."

Is this still a thing?

Comment: +1. I don't think so. Blowing the smoke away from a fired gun is probably more popular in Bollywood movies.

Comment: You know, I made that gesture many times as a kid, and saw others do it (it was popular in the 1950s), but never knew until now what it meant. Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: It's been slightly amended to brushing the dust from your shoulders.

Answer (score 16):

It's called ***buffing [one's] nails*** and might originate from the Bugs Bunny cartoon. [Source](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.anthropology/2006-06/msg00020.html)

Comment: That one guy on the internet saw it on Bugs Bunny once isn't, to me, a very compelling origin story.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that there are two gestures here. The first one is buffing his or her nails.. and the second one is "wiping dirt off of your shoulder" or "Brushing it off" which kind of indicates that something is "no big deal" or even that they are better than the thing they are brushing off... its a bit of a showboat.

Comment: Hi, @klyra, thanks for the answer. Not sure if this is what Jony Agarwal is looking for. He's already aware of what the gesture is conveying; an explanation is contained within his question. Instead, he's asking for a **concise phrase**, if one exists, to take the place of describing the entire action—but it seems like your response is describing the entire action again instead of offering that concise phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I’m old enough to remember doing this in grade school. We thought it was polishing the medal you got for doing something well

Comment: Are you offering a name for the gesture, as the poster asked for?